# Leaflet feature click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, leaflet

I have a leaflet map with the boundaries of Europe countries. When the user clicks on a feature I get the name of Country by a field in geojson file.
I also have a datatable with data from database and I have a function on row click.
How I can perform a click on datatable row from leaflet feature click?
The problem: on feature click -> execute a function

With the below code I get Feature Name and search on datatable

```js
    layer_europe_with_data_0.on('click', function(e) {       
    var dd = e.layer.feature.properties.NAME_ENGL
    var tbldump = $('#europetbl').DataTable();        
    tbldump.search(dd).draw();
    }
```

One way was that I found the search option on datatable, so I can search on datatable for the row. But I can perform the click on.

The function on row click

```js
    $('#europetbl tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    // bla bla bla
    }
```

I want to do this:

```js
    layer_europe_with_data_0.on('click', function(e) {
    do this $('#europetbl tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    }
```

code for row click

```js
    $('#europetbl tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var tbl = $('#europetbl').DataTable();
    var dt = tbl.row( this ).data();
    mymap.setView([dt[4], dt[3]],6)
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
    tbl.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
    $("#fetchtbl tbody").html("");
    var id  = dt[0];
    idforcountrystats = id;
    localStorage.setItem("idforstats", idforcountrystats);
    $.ajax({
    url: "fetchdata.php",
    method: "POST",
    data:{id:id},
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data){
      if (data){
      var trHTML = '';
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            trHTML +='<tr><td><input type="checkbox" data-id="'+ item.fetID+'" 
    onclick="QuickView(this)"></td><td>' + item.Fua_name + '</td></tr>' ;
        });
        $('#fetchtbl tbody').append(trHTML); 
      }
    }
    })
    })
```

Comment: Just curious, what does the click on the datatable row do exactly? Why not just take out the functionality you need to be triggered on your row click into a function by itself, that seems to be a more pragmatic approach rather than trigger events elsewhere.

Comment: When the user clicks on the row, I have a database relation 1:N and I fetch with ajax, data from another table. I am rookie and I do not know how to do your way.

Comment: If you add some small snippets of the code you've mentioned to the question, we can see how we can refactor your code.